# Can't read csv file from azure datalake storage gen2 with spark submit using datastax

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, cassandra, datastax-enterprise, azure-data-lake-gen2

I want to use spark datastax to read csv file from azure datalake storage gen2. I use datastax 6.8.1. Hadoop is installed in datastax with version 2.7.1.4. The version of spark is 2.4.0.

When I launch the spark-submit, I have this issue java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.security.ProviderUtils.excludeIncompatibleCredentialProviders(Lorg/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration;Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration;

I found that the method excludeIncompatibleCredentialProviders does not exist in the jar hadoop-common 2.7.1.4 so I have added in my dependencies hadoop-client version 2.10.1 but this does not resolve my issue.

Here are the code:
pom.xml:

```
     <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>DataStax-Repo</id>
      <url>https://repo.datastax.com/public-repos/</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.delta</groupId>
      <artifactId>delta-core_2.11</artifactId>
      <version>0.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
      <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
      <version>2.10.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
      <artifactId>hadoop-azure</artifactId>
      <version>2.10.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spark -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
    <!--<testSourceDirectory>src/test/scala</testSourceDirectory>-->
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <!-- see http://davidb.github.com/scala-maven-plugin -->
        <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
              <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <args>
                <!--<arg>-make:transitive</arg>-->
                <arg>-dependencyfile</arg>
                <arg>${project.build.directory}/.scala_dependencies</arg>
              </args>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.18.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <useFile>false</useFile>
          <disableXmlReport>true</disableXmlReport>
          <!-- If you have classpath issue like NoDefClassError,... -->
          <!-- useManifestOnlyJar>false</useManifestOnlyJar -->
          <includes>
            <include>**/*Test.*</include>
            <include>**/*Suite.*</include>
          </includes>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
          </descriptorRefs>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
              <mainClass>org.example.App</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

App.scala

```
package org.example


import org.apache.log4j.Logger
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.de.datalake.atomekafkatoadls.utils.{Arguments, Config}



object App {
  val logger: Logger = Logger.getRootLogger

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val spark = createSparkSession()


    import spark.implicits._


    spark.read.option("header", true).option("delimiter", ";").csv("abfs://file_system@storage_account.dfs.core.windows.net/test.csv").show(false)

  def createSparkSession(): SparkSession = {
    SparkSession
      .builder
      .config("fs.default.name", "abfs://file_system@storage_account.dfs.core.windows.net")
      .config("fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.ClientCredsTokenProvider")
      .config("fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint", "******")
      .config("fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id", "******")
      .config("fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret", "******")
      .config("fs.azure.account.auth.type", "OAuth")
      .config("fs.adl.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.adl.AdlFileSystem")
      .config("fs.abfs.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AzureBlobFileSystem")
      .config("fs.AbstractFileSystem.abfs.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.Abfs")
      .config("dfs.adls.oauth2.access.token.provider.type", "ClientCredential")
      //.config("fs.azure.createRemoteFileSystemDuringInitialization", "true")
      //.master("local")
      .getOrCreate()
  }

  
}
```

spark-submit script:

```
sudo dse -u user -p password spark-submit  --verbose   --name "SPARK"  --deploy-mode client   --executor-memory 8G --num-executors 6   --executor-cores 3 --driver-memory 4g --conf spark.cassandra.auth.username=user --conf spark.cassandra.auth.password=password --conf "spark.rpc.askTimeout=2500" --conf "spark.cassandra.connection.keepAliveMS=10800000" --conf "spark.cassandra.query.retry.count=-1"  example.jar
```

I have added the jar of hadoop-common:2.10.1 in the spark-classpath but I can not overload the version 2.7.1.4 of hadoop-common with the version 2.10.1.
Any help please ?